# Crossdomain.xml on a multisite setup

Tags: 7, multi-sites

I can't figure out where I need to place the crossdomain.xml (to let Flash communicate).

If I place it on the root of my Drupal installation, the cross-domain-policy is not working because the symlink redirects the user-agent to the multisite folder.

If I place the crossdomain.xml in the multisite folder, it doesn't work either.

What should I try?

Comment: Just placing the crossdomain.xml in the root worked in the end. The problem was in the flash app.

Answer (score 3):

I would make up a module with a [`hook_menu`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7) in it with a path of "crossdomain.xml".  In the menu callback, figure out your domain and serve up the proper file with the proper MIME type.  Install the module in "sites/all" and enable for each site that needs it.

I also suspect you could handle it in .htaccess with something like

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.host1\.com [NC]
RewriteRule crossdomain.xml crossdomain.host1.xml [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.host2\.com [NC]
RewriteRule crossdomain.xml crossdomain.host2.xml [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.host3\.com [NC]
RewriteRule crossdomain.xml crossdomain.host3.xml [L]
```

Answer (score -1):

The docroot is the correct place for it to go. You should not have any symlinks either.

Comment: Docroot doesn't work. As stated in my question. I use symlinks because it is a multi-site setup.

Comment: @cateye I don't understand "because the symlink redirects the user-agent to the multisite folder." You should not have any symlinks to the multisite folder.